# Java Logger logs everything

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I am using java.util.logging.
I want 2 logs - one for time measurements and one for all other things.
The problem is that the timer logger still logs everything, how do I tell it to log only what I send to logTime method?

```
import configurations.ConfigReader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.*;

import configurations.Time;
import main.Main;
/**
* Created by giladba on 27/01/2016.
*/
public class LogManager {
    private static final String LOGS_PATH = (String) ConfigReader.get(ConfigReader.Field.LOGS);
    private static Logger globalLogger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
    private static Logger timingLogger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    static {
        initLoggers(globalLogger, (String) ConfigReader.get(ConfigReader.Field.ST_VIEW));
        initLoggers(timingLogger, ConfigReader.get(ConfigReader.Field.ST_VIEW) + "_timing");
        timingLogger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    }

    public synchronized static void log(String message) {
        globalLogger.info(message);
    }

    public synchronized static void logTime(String action, long time1, long time2) {
        timingLogger.info(Time.getTimeNowFormatted() + action + "\t\t : " + (time2-time1) + " ms");
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the logger.
     * @throws SecurityException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static void initLoggers(Logger curLog, String name) throws SecurityException {
        FileHandler procHandler = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(LOGS_PATH);
            if(!file.exists())
                file.mkdirs();
            procHandler = new FileHandler(LOGS_PATH + name + "_log.out", 2048000, 20, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        procHandler.setFormatter(new MyFormatter());

        procHandler.setLevel(Level.INFO);

        curLog.addHandler(procHandler);
        curLog.setUseParentHandlers(true);
        curLog.info("\n");
        curLog.info("--------" + (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy_HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date()) + "--------");
    }

    /**
     * simple naked formatter for the log files.
     * @author jeremieg
     *
     */
    static class MyFormatter extends Formatter {

        @Override
        public String format(LogRecord arg0) {
            return arg0.getMessage() + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your logging configuraton ? Besides that: you might want to decide whether using a different framework like slf4j or log4j / log4j2 is a better fit for you.

Comment: Indeed switch to a modern framework like SLF4J.

Comment: Which configurations are you referring to? if you are talking about ConfigReader all it does is return a path to the directory i want to put the logs in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static Logger globalLogger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
private static Logger timingLogger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
```

That is the same logger, and as a result, your configuration gets mixed up.

You have to give two different names to `Logger.getLogger` to get two different loggers.